# Make TextView as wide as possible without crowding out other views

Tags: android, android-layout

I want the following layout handling in my app:

[image]

As you can see, the text is allowed to be as wide as it can be without pushing off the screen the other views that appear to its right, ellipsizing as necessary. There will never be more than 3 color swatches, and no fewer than 1, and all swatches and the x in the circle must always be visible. **When the text is short, it should behave as seen in the last 2 rows (the ferns)**.

I've tried to put the text and images in a `LinearLayout`, but when the text is too long the images are not visible (or not entirely visible). I assume there's some way to indicate that the images should always take up as much room as they need, with the `TextView` taking up the rest or as much as it needs, but I can't seem to figure out how. I don't know if a `RelativeLayout` would work better for this, or maybe a `TableLayout`/`TableRow` or `GridLayout`, though nothing I've read seems to cover this situation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/plant_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/color_0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_remove_plant"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/color_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_remove_plant"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/color_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_remove_plant"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/remove_plant"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_remove_plant"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @TimCastelijns I see. I overlooked that.

Comment: You could use a RelativeLayout, starting at the right, moving your way left with your views. Calling layout_alignParentRight="true" on the first, and layout_toLeftOf="@id/id_of_view_to_the_right" for each of the following views. For the last view, make the width match_parent and set the layout to the left of the final color view.

Comment: @zgc7009 how would you handle the bottom 2 rows, where the rightmost view is not anchored to the right edge?

Comment: @TimCastelijns misread the question, thought the issue was that the last 2 was supposed to look like the rest of them (everything but the text pushed right).

Comment: is this a ListView or a fixed layout ?

Comment: @Anonymous The parent view is also a `LinearLayout`, a vertical one, of course.

Comment: that's not what I'm saying. are you showing these rows in a ListView with a ListView adapter ? post your code.

Comment: @Anonymous I was referring to the parent of the rows shown above--it's a LinearLayout, as is each row. I've posted the code for the rows (each plant). The xml of the parent is in the layout for the activity. I add each row to the parent programmatically. The ImageView in each of the lowest level LinearLayouts is just there to make the swatches the same size as the "remove button" (x with circle). That's why it's invisible. I'm open to different approaches, though a ListView doesn't seem like a good solution.

Comment: I think I found a layout that matches all of your requirements without the need for any computation. It should also work inside of a `ListView` if you switch to one later.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a working layout. Two things that are happening. One, the rows are using `LinearLayout` with `layout_width="wrap_content"`. This keeps the `LinearLayout` from expanding beyond its content keeping everything left aligned (your bottom two examples). Two, the `TextView` is using `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_width="0dp"` to tell the `LinearLayout` that it should expand this `TextView` to fill the rest of the space of available but to not push out the other views (your top three examples). Note: this is not all `layout_weight` does, only that this is what it is doing in this context.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="This is a long line of text and is testing something. This is a long line of text and is testing something. This is a long line of text and is testing something." />

        <View
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:background="#F00" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:background="#0F0" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:background="#00F" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="This is a long line of text and is testing something. This is a long line of text and is testing something. This is a long line of text and is testing something." />

        <View
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:background="#F00" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:background="#0F0" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="This is some line of text." />

        <View
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:background="#F00" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:background="#00F" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="This is short" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:background="#F00" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The rows with long names work, but I'm seeing the images right justified for rows with short names. I did change the layout_width on the horizontal LinearLayout to be wrap_content, but no dice (tho it makes sense to do that). 1 difference I see with your example vs. what I have is that the widths of your other views are fixed sizes. I experimented with that, too, and didn't see a difference. BTW, I have used layout_weight before, but I'm surprised that it does what it does here. (It seems that setting it to 1 for one view and not at all on the others would, if anything, make matters worse....)

Comment: I may have to settle for the images being right justified, which is really not a big deal. The key thing is that now as much text as possible is shown when the text is long (which I guess could also be accomplished by switching to a RelativeLayout, as others pointed out). Thanks.

Comment: I was a bit surprised at how difficult it was to get something to work. The wrap_content vs match_parent interaction with layout_weight was interesting.

Comment: Welcome to Android, where it's always difficult to get something to work :-)

Answer (score 0):

This code gives you the screen size in dp and pixels. Set your images at a fixed size that you like, for example 30dp or Math.min(screenWidth,screenHeight)/100 to set it relative to the display size.
After that, since you know how many images will be shown substruct the (number of images) * imageSize from the tottal screenWidth and set this as the textview width

```
WindowManager wm2 = (WindowManager) con.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm2.getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();   display.getMetrics(outMetrics);
float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
dpHeight  = (int) (outMetrics.heightPixels / density); 
dpWidth  = (int) (outMetrics.widthPixels / density);
screenWidth=outMetrics.widthPixels; 
screenHeight=outMetrics.heightPixels;
```

this is how you set the textview's width programmatically

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams)textView.getLayoutParams();
params.width=/calculated size/; 
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd rather try to measure the image sizes than to set them to fixed sizes, since the latter seems a bit risky and hacky, even when the size is relative to the screen size. Measuring view sizes in Android is generally a challenge, though, in my experience. Another issue is that I don't want to allocate all remaining space to the TextView: in the last 2 rows in my example, I only want it to use as much as space as it needs and then have the images be immediately to its right. I could maybe check the length of the text first, though, and do some sort of conditional formatting.

Comment: 1) i mentioned the image size-relative to display size as an option. you can set it to fixed number of dp as i allready showed you in the code snippet.
2)the whole point of this approach is to limit the textview width in the case that it's going to push out the images. otherwise you don't have to set anything. so.. if(textview_width> space_left){limit_textview_width()}

Comment: My concern was more with setting the TextView to a fixed size generally, relative to screen size or not, since my preference is to let Android handle the sizing, though it's a definitely an option. I may try to do what you're suggesting or maybe put the images together in a LinearLayout, try to measure that, and then do what you suggest in the second part of your last comment. I was really hoping that one of Android's layouts (or a combination) would let me accomplish what I'm trying to do, though.

Comment: Also, "`if(textview_width>...`" requires measuring the TextView, so there would still be the challenge of measuring a view (though that is doable).

Answer (score 0):

> When the text is short, it should behave as seen in the last 2 rows (the ferns).

I don't think that a standard layout is going to give you what you want. My guess is that you will have to create a custom `ViewGroup` that implements your requirements. Qberticus' implementation is probably as close as you'll get using out-of-the-box layouts.

That being said, I can't rule out `GridLayout` being able to pull this off, somehow.

Personally, I'd go with a `TableLayout`, with four columns for your color swatches and X icons, and a fifth column for the text. You could dynamically construct the table rows to have the text fill columns that are not going to be used by swatches, and you would use `android:strechColums="0"` to give all extra space to the left-most column where the text is based. As with Qberticus' approach, this leaves you with right-flush swatches and icons, which IMHO is a better UI.

If your concern with the right-flush swatches and icons is having gaps of whitespace between the text and the swatches/icons, make the text have right `gravity` (or `end` if you are support RTL languages).